# MySQL - how to round

Tags: mysql

I have this in one of my queries:

```
FORMAT(ROUND(AVG(`rating` * 2)) / 2, 1) AS `average_rating`
```

If `rating` has a value of, say, 1.45 - then I get 1.5, which is what I want. When it rounds to whole numbers, I get 1.0, 2.0, etc. I don't want that. When I get whole numbers, I'd like to drop the decimal value.

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in this way :

```
(TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM(CAST(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM 
FORMAT(ROUND(AVG(`rating` * 2)
) / 2, 1))AS char)))) AS `average_rating`
```